# Suppose X1,...,Xn are iid N($\mu$,1). Find the UMVUE of $\mu^2$

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

This question is part of my exam study guide (and not for marks). I am given a solution. However, I am having trouble following it.

The solution given is:

$V[\bar{X}]=E[\bar{X}^2]-E[\bar{X}]^2$

$\Longrightarrow \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}=E[\bar{X}^2]-\mu^2$

$ \Longrightarrow E[\bar{X}^2]= \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n} + \mu^2 $

We know $\sigma^2=1$ $ \Longrightarrow E[\bar{X}^2]= \frac{1}{n} + \mu^2$

Let $S(X)=\bar{X}^{2}-\frac{1}{n}$. It is unbiased, and a function of $\bar{X}$, the complete sufficient statistic. Therefore, it is UMVUE.

Done.

I am having trouble understanding the solution. Particularly how S(X) was chosen, and how it followed that is is UMVUE. I understand that Lehman-Scheffe was used, however I would like an explanation to help me understand exactly what went into this solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from the typo $S=\bar X^2-\frac1n$, everything else is quite clearly mentioned. *Lehmann-Scheffe* says an unbiased estimator based on a complete sufficient statistic is UMVUE.

Comment: I suppose I am just not entirely sure I understand Lehman-Scheffe, and how to efficiently use it.